# Switching between background 64 bit processing and 32 (so I can use 3rd party ie XTools)

Tags: python, arcpy, geoprocessing, 64bit, 32bit

I often run scripts now with 64 bit background processing enabled but when I want to use certain tools like Xtools table to text I have to turn it off as these tools are 32 bit. Is there a way to switch this within a script say... (Geoprocessing_Enable is fictional)

```
#start at 64 then change to 32 for Xtools
arcpy.Geoprocessing_Enable(32)

arcpy.XToolsPro_Table2Text(in, out, fields)

#go back to 64 after 32 bit tool ran successfully
arcpy.Geoprocessing_Enable(64)
```

Is there anything equivalent to doing this?

Comment: This is a question better asked on http://stackoverflow.com/...

Comment: I disagree. As the OP's question is directly related to ArcPy, this is more than appropriate to this exchange.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Once you've started executing your script at prompt, you're in either the 32 or 64 bit space.
[yes you could do some sort of multiprocess or os.system call out to 32 or 64bit, but thats at your own risk and I've heard nothing but problems when people do this.]

See this [blog article](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/11/12/python-scripting-with-64-bit-processing/) about specifying what "bits" to run against.
In short, you'll need to break up your script into pieces and call them against the version of Python they work with.

Comment: KHibma, thanks. Figure I'll stay in 32 for all scripts rather than split. Most of my big merges(joins) are in Stata64 .do files now.